# Concatenate all values for a column as one string for each row in select

Tags: string, subquery, concatenation

I have been looking into this issue for some time and need some help. I have looked into sub-queries and CTE with no Luck.

I want to create a select of all of the data in **Table A**. I also want to add some columns from **Table B**. So an Inner join will work initially.

However in **Table B** I want to create a string that is concatenated from all the different categories for each person and list this as a column in my select.

For example, one person might be in IT and also Construction categories so I would like a string that says "Construction, IT" listed for that person and the same basis for all others.

I believe I have looked into COALESCE
which meets me part way. Any advice most appreciated.

**Table A**
Name
Surname
Person Ref

**Table B**
Person Ref
Person Category
Person Gender

These are example tables I can't post the ones I'm looking at for security reasons but hopefully, you get my point.

Martin

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Show us some sample data from each table.  What have you tried thus far?

Comment: Table A Results
First Name
Tony

Surname
Stark

Age
50

Table B results
Person Category
Category 1
Category 2
Category 3

My select results needed
First name
Tony

Surname
Stark

Age 
50

All categories (invented category)
Category 1, Category 2, Category 3 --all this is in a single string

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: As I said previously I dont feel comfortable with posting my actual data for security reasons see my first comment though for the output im expecting to see